# Rails Share Active Storage (Service AWS) between two applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I builded an application with active storage (service: AWS) to store an avatar to the User Model.
Everything worked as expected. (Files can be uploaded and the avatar can be presented within the view)
I then duplicated the project, but the User Model of the second project isn't finding the attachment:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Can't resolve image into URL: to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil)
```

Unfortunately if I upload something from the first project and run `User.first.avatar.attached?` from the console, the result is true.
If I then run the same command from the second project, the result is false.

- database.yml, storage.yml, User Model are the same in both projects.
- config.active_storage.service = :amazon is set in all environments in both projects.

How could the second project not find the attachment if even the databases and setup of active storage are the same?

Comment: Did you copy the database entries? active storage uses 2 tables active_storage_attachments and active_storage_blobs which holds the references to the records with attachments, the blobs and the keys on amazon.

Comment: I use the same database and the same tables in both projects.
Meaning both database.yml files are identical / same